# What Is the Implied Contrast Between These Clauses Linked by 'But'?

Tags: coordination

It's generally understood that the coordination conjunction 'but' is used to create contrast between different constituents (e.g. positive against negative, good against better, bad against worse). However, there are many examples where the contrast is less overt, particularly when 'but' is used to connect independent clauses.

I believe, though correct me if I'm wrong, that the contrast is created by subtext, an understanding held by the writer/speaker and thought to be understood by the reader/listener.

In the following clauses, what is the understood contrast between the coordinating elements? I've added my thoughts alongside each example:

> [1] She lost a great deal of respect for him in that moment, but she would never admit it.

In 1, I can't see any obvious contrast between her losing respect and never admitting it. Are we to take it that the contrast stems from an inferred belief that she would admit it if she felt it?

> [2] He stared at the mess, but he tried to hide his unease.

In 2, is it to be understood that him staring at the mess implies unease and that this is contrasted with him trying to appear as though he's not uneasy?

> [3] He went the pub, but she wasn't there.

In 3, I believe there is the understood idea that he went to the pub to find/see her, which implies that he believes she is there, and this contrasts with her not being there.

> [4] He started crying, but he pretended that he wasn't.

Example 4 is perhaps the most obvious contrast, but I've included it because it isn't as simple as 'He started crying, but he stopped.' He is still crying, so the only contrast can come from the fact that he appears not to be.

> [5] Maybe I'm wrong, but correct me if I am.

This last example, a direct quote from Oprah, is interesting because the two clauses seem to agree with each other (they're both negative, that is, at the surface level). However, the use of 'but' almost implies that she thinks she isn't wrong and that the 'maybe' is her saying, 'I don't think I'm wrong.'

Comment: Ouch. Downvoted for a misunderstanding on an English Learners forum. I'm assuming the reason relates to the Cambridge definition, but I would appreciate some elaboration. Though I'm not saying it's incorrect, that's a very broad explanation that would make 'but' practically synonymous with any other conjunction, which it isn't.

Comment: The Oprah quote is an odd one.  Perhaps it was just an off the cuff remark. I would say "so" would be a more natural conjunction to use there.

Comment: I don't think the question deserved to be downvoted, though I think you've answered your own question: "... the contrast is created by subtext, an understanding held by the writer/speaker and thought to be understood by the reader/listener."  To which I'd add that immediate *context* often supplies that understanding in an overt manner, and so  to look at sentences in isolation can be to go down a rabbit hole.

Comment: Oprah's remark "Maybe I'm wrong" = "I strongly suspect that I'm right".

Comment: @BillyKerr I agree, definitely. It's not the conjunction I would've chosen, but it's a direct quote that I found on Ludwig, so it's an interesting real-world example to dissect. The others were derived from real quotes, but not identical.

Comment: @TimR Thanks for your answer, Tim. I'm not a fan of trusting my own analysis unless I have evidence to support it, which I was struggling to find online. If people agree with me, that's great, but I'm always open to filling gaps in my knowledge. Downvotes can be quite off-putting, though.

Comment: @MJAda - it doesn't matter if its a direct quote.  People can and do make mistakes, or perhaps they just can't find the right word in the heat of the moment. Don't assume everything everybody says is worth analysing. Humans aren't grammar robots.

Comment: @BillyKerr That's a valid point.

Comment: It's hardly a "subtext"  that people who have seriously downgraded their opinion about someone *usually make their feelings known*. That's normal human nature, ***but*** some people in some contexts keep quiet about their revised opinions - to the extent of not even correcting others who assume they still have the same *high* regard for the subject they had before.